# Web Audio Api destination maxChannelCount always is 2 on Linux

Tags: linux, electron, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I have a problem with Web Audio API and an usb audio interface on Linux;

I wrote some audio player code on Web Audio API.

Everything is alright when I connect my 7.1 USB Audio Interface (TASCAM 16x08 - there are 8 output channels) and start my APP on Windows machine. `context.destination.maxChannelCount` equals 8 and I can select the channel to output the sound.

But when I do the same on Linux machine `context.destination.maxChannelCount` always is 2 (stereo).

I tried to:

- create virtual audio multichannel device = same result - always only 2 maxChannelCount;
- setting alsa, pulseaudio, jack audio connection kit and more...

The result is the same: in my code `context.destination.maxChannelCount` is always is 2
but the operating systems settings dialog detects 8 channels.

This is some code to be clear:

```
var context = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
var audio = new Audio();
var source = context.createMediaElementSource(audio);
source.connect(context.destination);
audio.src = 'audio.mp3';
audio.play();

console.log(context.destination.maxChannelCount);  //output on win:   2
                                                            on linux: 8
```

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

I found solution here https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1072792.html

> solved it by editing /etc/pulse/daemon.conf. 
>   ; default-sample-channels
>   = 2 uncomment the line and add more channels.

Comment: Setting it to `default-sample-channels = 6` in my `~/.pulse/daemon.conf` file fixed it for me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What browser are you running? Browser is responsible for giving you those available outputs, if they're not there (in all available browsers) then i think you're out of luck. I have done some things with Web Audio and multiple outputs and even on the same OS i got different results from different browsers.

Comment: I use electron js - my browser is Chromium. It`s looks like Chromium in linux can not detect device channel count and set it for 2 as default

Comment: Try and see what number of outputs you get in different browsers on linux. I assume you have that audio interface working correctly in linux? as in you have somewhere in the OS saying that you have 8 outputs available?

Comment: It can be Chromium, but can also be something else. Does your OS say you have 8 outputs?